# PHP Generate Dynamic Function calls array

Tags: php, laravel, multithreading, swoole, octane

I am using php laravel threading using octane and swoole server for concurrent processing.

when I pass static process function list as below it works.

```
$ArrayProcess = [
            fn () => $this->getPropertyData(),
            fn () => $this->getPropertyData(),
            fn () => $this->getPropertyData()
        ];
        try {
            $result = Octane::concurrently($ArrayProcess, 200000);
            print_r(json_encode($result));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            print_r($e->getLine() . ':' . $e->getMessage() . ' ');
            dd($e->getTrace());
        }
```

**Output of above**

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => Closure() {#552 ▼
    class: "App\Http\Controllers\OctaneController"
    this: App\Http\Controllers\OctaneController {#489 …}
    file: "/home/devbooki/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/OctaneController.php"
    line: "72 to 72"
  }
  1 => Closure() {#543 ▼
    class: "App\Http\Controllers\OctaneController"
    this: App\Http\Controllers\OctaneController {#489 …}
    file: "/home/devbooki/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/OctaneController.php"
    line: "73 to 73"
  }
  2 => Closure() {#547 ▼
    class: "App\Http\Controllers\OctaneController"
    this: App\Http\Controllers\OctaneController {#489 …}
    file: "/home/devbooki/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/OctaneController.php"
    line: "74 to 75"
  }
]
```

but when I am trying to generate process array dynamically it is not working.

```
$ArrayProcess = [];
foreach ($PropertyData as $PD) {
   $ArrayProcess[] = fn () => $this->getPropertyData();
}
$PropertyData = Octane::concurrently($ArrayProcess, 200000);
```

**Output of above**

```
[[{},{},{},{}]]
```

Please suggest way how to generate process array dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try to compare your $arrayProcess from static and dynamic ?

Comment: yes I have sharing output

Comment: static  dd($ArrayProcess); gives following result

Comment: array:3 [▼
  0 => Closure() {#537 ▼
    class: "App\Http\Controllers\OctaneController"
    this: App\Http\Controllers\OctaneController {#453 …}
    file: "/home/devbooki/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/OctaneController.php"
    line: "72 to 72"
  }
 ]

Comment: dynamic dd($ArrayProcess); gives following result

Comment: [[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]]

Comment: Modify your post with result

Comment: @GaryHoubre added output. please check.

Comment: Found way to generate processes array dynamically.

Comment: $ArrayProcess = [];
                    foreach ($PropertyData as $PD) {
                        $PropertyID = $PD["propertyId"];
                        array_push($ArrayProcess, fn () => $this->getPricingData($PropertyID));
                    }